# Is there a utility like rsync, but with the speed of btrfs COW?

Tags: rsync, backup, scp, btrfs, timestamps

`rsync` has various performance issues; I have never been able to make it perform a sync in `O(#changes)`. Even if it uses modification time and not checksums, it still needs to generate a list of all changes files, which may take hours or run into some arbitrary limits. It is clearly possible however, for example with a copy-on-write filesystem, you can instantly transfer a 'minimal' diff without the minutes-long (or hours-long) overhead of rescanning the hard drive.

And certainly it would be possible with the following algorithm:

- `my-ideal-rsync --modified-since "2020-10-10 12:00:00"` would list/send/stream the modified files in optimal O(# modified files) time rather than O(# files on disk) time by recursively looking at each folder, and checking the folder's last-modified time if it's been modified since the time of the last transfer in the given command
- alternatively, `my-ideal-rsync2` could do so without the above flag, by recursively comparing the folders of each system in lock-step:

  - recursively from the root, align all child inodes into pairs (source,dest):

    - if the source inode has the same last-modified time, don't recurse
    - if the source inode has a newer last-modified time, recurse if a directory (or send if a file)
    - if the source inode has an older last-modified time, throw an error
    - if the source or dest inode is missing, queue it for a possible `mv` operation, i.e. a queue of possible matches
  - (if a match is not found by the end of the recursion, then perform a deletion or creation, respectively)

Maybe there's a bug in the above algorithm, but it illustrates the concept. Is there anything like this?

Comment: Directory modification times are independent of file modification times.

Comment: Why not use [`btrfs send`](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Manpage/btrfs-send)?

Answer (score 0):

> Directory modification times are independent of file modification times. – roaima Jan 29 at 7:41

Due to my misunderstanding of directory modification times (at least on ext4, etc.), it seems such an algorithm is not possible, in the absence of using a filesystem that provides "a file in a subdirectory has been changed"-time. (Or, alternatively, setting the fs into read-only unless a file modification daemon is running to keep track of changes to later rsync... ew.)

Going to answer this tentatively as "such an algorithm is likely undoable with a normal filesystem because dir mtimes are independent of file mtimes; just use `btrfs send`

Answer (score -1):

The rsync program does not **record** the difference, so it have to scan the entire directory tree.

In contrast, the `git` version control system tracks modifications made to files and directories and keeps all history, so that may be what you need.